# do while loop is not working as I expected in `===` state?

Tags: php, arrays, logical-operators

```
<?php
    $customer = ["aa_","aa_","aa_","aa_"];
      $i = 0;
      do{
        $customer[$i] = $customer[$i].$i;
        $i++;
      } while ($i === 4);
      echo $i;   //print only 1
      var_dump($customer);  
    ?>
```

`$customer` real output

```
array (size=4)
      0 => string 'aa_0' (length=4)
      1 => string 'aa_' (length=4)
      2 => string 'aa_' (length=4)
      3 => string 'aa_' (length=4)
```

When I use `while ($i < 4)` is working .But here I misunderstand is why using about condition is getting only loop for one times...I think it should be

```
   do $i++ -> 1  ( 1 === 4 ) loop again 
   do $i++ -> 2  ( 2 === 4 ) loop again 
   do $i++ -> 3  ( 3 === 4 ) loop again 
   do $i++ -> 4  ( 4 === 4 ) stop quit
```

so expected `$customer` output is

```
array (size=4)
      0 => string 'aa_0' (length=4)
      1 => string 'aa_1' (length=4)
      2 => string 'aa_2' (length=4)
      3 => string 'aa_3' (length=4)
```

Comment: That really seems like you need sleep :P `( 1 === 4 ) loop again` <- I don't think it helps if you read it 10 times again, but `1` was never the same as `4`. The loop runs again if the condition evaluates to TRUE, so 1,2,3 would need to be the same as 4 to be true.

Comment: Also the reason why it's initially running is in the documentation [_The main difference from regular while loops is that the first iteration of a do-while loop is guaranteed to run_](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 you r right ,  :(p)  I might take a rest !!! Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

No, your interpretation is wrong.

```
$i = 0 // Starting value
do (Will do the action here)  $i++ -> 1  
CONDITION ( 1 === 4 ) -> FALSE so it will not loop, (Stop the loop) so $i is only = 1;
```

If you really want to use equals in your condition, you should use `!==` (not equal), like this below:

```
$i = 0;
do{
    $customer[$i] = $customer[$i].$i;
    $i++;
} while ($i !== 4);
```

So the explanation is this

```
$i = 0 // Starting value
do (Will do the action here)  $i++ -> 1  
CONDITION ( 1 !== 4 ) -> TRUE (Loop continues)
do (Will do the action here)  $i++ -> 2  
CONDITION ( 2 !== 4 ) -> TRUE (Loop continues)
do (Will do the action here)  $i++ -> 3  
CONDITION ( 3 !== 4 ) -> TRUE (Loop continues)
do (Will do the action here)  $i++ -> 4   
CONDITION ( 4 !== 4 ) -> FALSE (Stops the loop)
Final value of $i will be 4.
```

Comment: I agree with what's being said here... was about to answer the same but was too slow.. :)